# Running code on boot android

Tags: java, android, service, toast, boot

I'm having issues getting code to run on boot, I've downloaded the source for an example that should work, but it doesn't. according to the example, it should produce a toast when the phones turned on, but it doesn't happen, I've tested on android 6.0 and 7.0.

 any help is appreciated thanks.
The code is as follows:
Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidautostartup"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
    </uses-permission>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver
            android:name=".BootComplete"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".AutoStartUp" >
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidautostartup.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

BootComplete.java

```
public class BootComplete extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, AutoStartUp.class);
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

AutoStartUp.java

```
public class AutoStartUp extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // do something when the service is created
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really wouldn't recommend doing UI stuff on a worker thread (service). While it can be done, it generates confusion for the user to receive a message outside an app context.

Having said that, if you need to do this you should be running UI code on the UI thread.

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

handler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sorry, where should i put that? inside the onCreate method?

Comment: you could actually call it on the reciever. Or in any of the lifecycle callback on the service , ideally onStart

Comment: it just gives me an error saying cannot resolve method makeText anonymous java.lang.runnable, java.lang.string, int

Comment: my bad you should be referencing a context, not THIS. I've edited my answer

Comment: I'd just like to point out that this is an example, I'm making another app that i need to make set alarms on boot, i just though ti should start with getting something to work on boot first, then move to setting the alarms

Comment: the updated answer gives me a new error "cannot resolve method makeText java.secutity.AccessControlContext, java.lang.string, int"

Comment: you are passing the wring kind of Contaxt, you should be using an instance of android.context.Context (like activity or service)

Comment: I'm going to have to do some more research on this because I have no idea what that means :/